# How to use If statement in javascript chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension (Game), and I am implementing a back button.
the button works, but when I try to make a popup every 5th time, it doesn't work.

currently this is my code:

```js
window.onload = function() {myFunction()};
function myFunction() {
  
  if (localStorage.getItem('back') === null) {
  localStorage.setItem('back', 0)
  
}



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var Undo = document.getElementById('undo');
Undo.addEventListener('click', function() {


if (localStorage.getItem('back') > 1) {
  local = localStorage.getItem('back')
  localStorage.setItem('back', local - 1)
  handle_undo();
} else {
  localStorage.setItem('back', '5')
  // just to display if it works:
  document.write(localStorage.getItem('back'));
}

});})
```

```html
<button class="undo-button" id="undo"  target="_blank">UNDO</button>
```

What I am trying to get is:

- On window load, find if localstorage with the key "back" exists, and create on with a value of 0
- When the button is pressed, and it equals 0, set to 5 (will create ads later)
- when button is pressed and does not equal 0, change by minus 1

Thanks in advance, -Fred

Comment: Is it a content script or what? If it is, you may need to use chrome.storage.local as shown in the documentation and tutorials. Also, DOMContentLoaded won't fire on navigating back in case the site implements HTML5 [History API](https://devdocs.io/dom/history_api), you would need to listen to [popstate](https://devdocs.io/dom_events/popstate) event, presumably.

Comment: you do not provide `handle_undo()`

Comment: thats in the real code, sorry @tuhin47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: 
I just need to say if localstorage is not greater than 1, set it to 5 which works if it is null

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.getElementById('undo').addEventListener('click', function() {

if (localStorage.getItem('back') > 1) {
  local = localStorage.getItem('back')
  localStorage.setItem('back', local - 1)
  handle_undo();
} else {
  localStorage.setItem('back', '5')
}

});})
```

```html
<button class="undo-button" id="undo"  target="_blank">UNDO</button>
```

thanks for your help guys!